# C++ Glibc Detected error. Double Free or corruption

Tags: c++, glibc

The goal of my assignment is to be able to read in a string of characters and list the vowels with their frequencies in the string and then display the number of consonants. My code compiles and always outputs the correct answer, however, if the string starts with a consonant it displays the glibc error.

my code: (note: a template was provided by the school so I have to base my code on said template.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES GO HERE:
void init_vectors(vector<char> & vowels, vector<int> & frequencies);
string read_text(const string & prompt);
bool is_alphabetic(const char character);
void create_list(const string & str_text, vector<char> & vec_text);
bool is_member(const vector<char> & list, char character);
int find_index(const vector<char> & list, char character);
int compute_vowel_freqs(const vector<char> & text, const vector<char> &        vowels, vector<int> & freqs);
void display_characters(const vector<char> & characters, const int    colwidth);
void display_freqs(const vector<int> & freqs, const int colwidth);

int main()
{
    // Define local variables and constants
    vector<char> vowels;
    vector<int> freqs;
    string input;
    vector<char> text;
    int consonants(0);

    const int COLUMNWIDTH = 2;

    // Initialize the list of vowels and vowel frequencies.
    init_vectors(vowels, freqs);
    // Call function init_vectors with variables vowels and freqs


    // Prompt the user for the input text by calling function read_text 
    input=read_text("Enter your text: ");

    // Copy the characters (ignoring non-alphabetic characters) in the input   string to the vector of characters in variable text
    // Call function create_list to do this
    create_list(input, text);

    // Compute the frequencies of vowels and consonants from the input text containing only alphabetic letters
    // Call function compute_vowel_freqs to do this
    compute_vowel_freqs(text, vowels, freqs);

    // Display the vowels and their frequencies
    // Call functions display_characters and display_freqs
    display_characters(vowels, COLUMNWIDTH);
        display_freqs(freqs, COLUMNWIDTH);  

    // Display the number of consonants. No function calls here.
    consonants = compute_vowel_freqs(text, vowels, freqs);
        cout<<"There are "<< consonants<< " consonants."<<endl;
  return 0;
}
     
// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS GO HERE:
void init_vectors(vector<char> & vowels, vector<int> & frequencies)
{

     for (int i(0); i<6; i++) //i = loop variable
    {
        frequencies.push_back(0);
    }
    vowels.push_back('a');
    vowels.push_back('e');
    vowels.push_back('i');
    vowels.push_back('o');
    vowels.push_back('u');
    vowels.push_back('y');
}

string read_text(const string & prompt)
{
    string phrase;
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin,phrase);
    return phrase;
}


bool is_alphabetic(const char character)
{
    bool alphabet;
    if ((character >= 'a' && character <= 'z')||(character >= 'A' &&  character <+ 'Z'))
        {
            alphabet = true;
        }
    return alphabet;
}

    void create_list(const string & str_text, vector<char> & vec_text)
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < str_text.length() ; i++)
    {
         if(is_alphabetic(str_text[i]))
            vec_text.push_back(str_text[i]);
    }
}

bool is_member(const vector<char> & list, char character)
{
    bool vowel;
    for (int i(0); i<=list.size(); i++)
    {
        if (character == list[i])
         {
            vowel=true;
         }
    }
    return vowel;
}

int find_index(const vector<char> & list, char character)
{
    int index = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(character == list[i])
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

int compute_vowel_freqs(const vector<char> & text, const vector<char> &      vowels, vector<int> & freqs)
{
    int num_cons(0);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < text.size() ; i++)
    {
    char c=tolower(text[i]);
        int index;
        if(is_member(vowels, text[i]))
        {
            index = find_index(vowels , tolower(text[i]));
            freqs[index]++;
        }
        else
         {

            num_cons++;
          }      

     }

    return num_cons;
}

void display_characters(const vector<char> & characters, const int colwidth)
{
    for(int i=0; i<characters.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<setw(colwidth)<<characters[i];
        if((i+1)<characters.size())
        {
            cout<<", ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

void display_freqs(const vector<int> & freqs, const int colwidth)
{
    for(int i=0; i<freqs.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<setw(colwidth)<<freqs[i];

        if((i+1)<freqs.size())
            cout<<", ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is undefined behavior in is_member().

is_member() fails to initialize the `vowel` bool.

As such, if the character is not a vowel, the value of the `vowel` bool is undefined. Its subsequent usage comprises undefined behavior.

I'm fairly certain that every modern C++ compiler, if all of its diagnostic warnings are turned on, would've detected this undefined behavior and issued a diagnostic.

There may be other problems with this code, I have not fully analyzed it, besides identifying this undefined behavior. I would suggest that you invest some time learning how to use a debugger, such as `gdb` (since you are apparently using a glibc-based platform), and a static analysis tool, such as `valgrind`, which will help you pin point these kinds of code bugs.

Comment: Your solution fully fixed my problem. I appreciate it! The code works perfect now.